# Do this Adapter Pattern example satisfy the GOF definition?

Tags: design-patterns

I need to know if this example meets the intention of the Adapter Pattern.

This example is intended to meet the **Pluggable Adapter** Pattern but it adapts two interfaces:

```
interface ITargetOld {
    double Precise(double i);
}

interface ITargetNew {
    string RoundEstimate(int i);
} 

public class Adapter : ITargetOld, ITargetNew {
    public double Precise(double i) {
        return i / 3;
    }

    public string RoundEstimate(int i) {
        return Math.Round(Precise(i)).ToString();
    }

    public string NewPrecise(int i) {
        return Precise(Convert.ToInt64(i)).ToString();
    }
}
```

The client would be:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        ITargetOld adapter1 = new Adapter();
        Console.WriteLine("Old division format (Precise) " + adapter1.Precise(5));

        ITargetNew adapter2 = new Adapter();
        Console.WriteLine("New division format (Round Estimate) " + adapter2.RoundEstimate(5));

        Adapter adapter3 = new Adapter();
        Console.WriteLine("New Precise format " + adapter3.NewPrecise(5));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Rafael

Answer (score 1):

To me, your code isn't really an adapter. The adapter pattern describes the case when you have an object of type A and want to use it in code that requires a type B.

```
interface A {
    method doSmthA();
}

interface B {
    method doSmthB();
}

class AdapterAToB implements B{
    private A a;
    constructor AdapterAToB(A a) {
         this.a = a;
    }

    method doSmthB() {
         a.doSomthA();
    }
}
```

in the case described above you convert an object of type A to the interface B and can use it in the places where you require instances of B.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I see your point but the definition says "Convert the interface of a class into another interface clients expect", and both codes (yours and mine) are doing that, a call based in ITargetNew is simply using the ITargetOld but transforming the calculation according to the ITargetNew "standards". Don't you agree?

Comment: you are not actually converting an object of type ITargetOld to ITargetNew. For example if I have an object o1 of type ITargetOld, there is no way I can use it in code that expects ITargetNew. I just can't convert between the two without creating another class.

Comment: It does, I called ((ITargetOld)adapter2).Precise(5) and ((ITargetNew)adapter1).RoundEstimate(5) and it worked nice (adapter2 is ITargetNew and adapter1 is ITargetOld). Both adapter1 and adapter2 can be used according to ITargetOld or ITargetNew.